# Withcolumn when isNotNull Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm getting the following error from the console:

> TypeError: _() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Here is the code used:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

start = '2020-10-20'
end = '2021-01-20'

country = 'es'
spark.conf.set('spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy', 'LEGACY')

dim_customers = (spark.table(f'nn_team_{country}.dim_customers')
           .select(f.col('customer_id').alias('customers'),
                   f.col('hello_pay_date').alias('hello_pay_date'),                    
                      )
                 .withColumn('HelloPay_user',
                             f.when((f.col('lidl_pay_date').isNotNull(1)).otherwise(0))
           ))
```

I tried several combinations of () but without result. Any idea about why I'm getting this error?

Comment: can you post full stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect. You should put 1 in the `when` clause, not inside `isnotnull`.

```
dim_customers = (spark.table(f'nn_team_{country}.dim_customers')
           .select(f.col('customer_id').alias('customers'),
                   f.col('hello_pay_date').alias('hello_pay_date'),                    
                      )
                 .withColumn('HelloPay_user',
                             f.when(f.col('lidl_pay_date').isNotNull(), 1).otherwise(0))
           ))
```

Comment: Hello @mck, Thanks for your answer, I tried your solution and works. But I have a question for you: why when you put .isNotNull() the 1 have to be "outside the () ? In the otherwise case it's inside the (). Thanks

Comment: It's the syntax of spark. You can read about it in the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.when) . isnotnull does not accept arguments. The `1` should be an argument of `when`, not of `isnotnull`. Similarly, `0` is an argument of `otherwise`.